# Não compila non-static variable e package does not exist

Tags: java

Podem me ajudar por favor, estou estudando Java e estou tendo os seguintes erros:

> ```
> Main.java:12: error: non-static variable carro1 cannot be referenced from a static context
>     carro1 = new aut.automovel("Chevette", 87);
>     ^ Main.java:12: error: package aut does not exist
>     carro1 = new aut.automovel("Chevette", 87);
> ```

Esse programa possui três classes: `Automoveis`, `Main` e `Motorista`.

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    private Automoveis carro1;
    private Motorista motorista1, motorista2;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Automoveis aut = new Automoveis();
        Motorista mot = new Motorista();
        carro1 = new aut.automovel("Chevette", 87);
        //carro1 = new aut.Automoveis("T",78);
        aut.displayMessage("Teste");
        //motorista1 = new mot.motorista("João", carro1);

        //motorista2 = new mot.motorista("Pedro",carro1);

        //System.out.println(motorista1.obterNome());
        //System.out.println(motorista2.obterNome());
    }
}
```

-

```java
public class Automoveis
{
    public String modelo;
    public int ano;
    private boolean ligado;

    //Instanciar automaovel
    public void automovel(String m, int a){
        modelo = m;
        ano = a;
        ligado = false;
    }

    //Ligar automóvel
    public void liga()
    {
        ligado = true;
    }

    public void desliga()
    {
        ligado = false;
    }

    public void displayMessage(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

-

```java
public class Motorista
{
    private String nome;
    private Automoveis carro;

    //Instanciar motorista
    public void motorista(String n, Automoveis a)
    {
        nome = n;
        carro = a;
    }

    //Obter nome do motorista
    public String obterNome()
    {
        return nome;
    }
    public Automoveis obterCarro()
    {
        return carro;
    }

}
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public void automovel(String m, int a){
> ```

Ora, isso era para ser um construtor, mas devido a presença daquele `void`, na verdade é um método. O que você queria era isso:

```
public Automoveis(String m, int a) {
```

No método `main`, ao invés disso:

> ```
>     Automoveis aut = new Automoveis();
>     Motorista mot = new Motorista();
>     carro1 = new aut.automovel("Chevette", 87);
> ```

Você deveria ter feito isso:

```
    Automoveis carro1 = new Automoveis("Chevette", 87);
    Motorista mot = new Motorista();
```

Observe que ao usar `new aut.automovel` você está tentando invocar um construtor (é isso que o uso do `new` significa). Mas o método `automovel` não é um construtor.

Ah, e vale ressaltar que é boa prática colocar o nome das classes no singular. Portanto, prefira usar `Automovel` ao invés de `Automoveis`.

Comment: Resolvido, era isso mesmo.  Quanto ao plural não sabia, vou usar a partir de agora! Obrigado.

Comment: @BrunoSouza Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, clique no "✔️" que está à esquerda da resposta para marcá-la como aceita/correta, o que também marca a sua pergunta como solucionada/respondida. Caso contrário, sinta-se livre para comentar.